# ubuntu squid proxy server error message

Tags: ubuntu, squid

I am doing some testing prior to installing squid on an ubuntu server 8.04 LTS and using webmin for the administration.
I have the server running and have added ACL's for my network to the squid config using webmin.
When I set my browser to use the squid server as a proxy server in ie I keep getting the error

•Access Denied. 
Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

I am new to running ubuntu without a GUI but I have follwed a few guides and have searched for the error but cant find a solution.

Comment: Please show us your squid ACLs. Oh, and you did restart/reload Squid after making config changes, right?

Comment: Yeah I did. I dont know what I did but it is now working.  I just rebuilt it from scratch following a different guide and the only change I can think is that I didnt have a static address which I think may have caused the issue.
I did rebuild on different hardware though so I will check it out tonight.
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Way I got it working was to build it from scratch and instead of using the webmin deb file I used the tar gz.
This is the guide I followed
http://ubuntulinuxhelp.com/faster-internet-with-an-old-laptop-ubuntu-and-squid/